# apply event after DOM modifies

Tags: jquery

This is probably a very common question but here it goes.
I created an image carousel for some small thumbs pics . When i click on a thumb it makes it slightly bigger and adds the id #click to it . I want to add the fancybox viewer if you click it again. Obviously $('a#click').click() did not work because the element is created afterwards, how to i make the script take into consideration these modifications ? I tryed

```
 $('a#click').live('click', function() {
   $(this).fancybox();
 });
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fancybox()` *attaches* the fancybox behavior, but it doesn't actually open it, it gets it ready for the *next* `click` event...so you need to trigger that handler it just attached.  The most optimal way is with [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) which will *only* trigger the handler and not bubble, like this:

```
 $('a#click').live('click', function() {
   $(this).fancybox().triggerHandler('click');
 });
```

Comment: worked just fine, i just had to add an e.preventDefault() because otherwise it would start loading the fancybox and halfway through take me to the link address.